# Conflict in JS Libraries

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I have a page acting as a landing page with a scroller which gives an easing and smooth scrolling, this also helps with  dropdown for links.
I then got a custom modal dialog login/sigup form integrated.

The problem is that when `<script src="assets/js/jquery.scrolly.min.js"></script>` is commented, the modal dialog dialog works but when it is available, modal dialog doesnt work. Can anyone please put me in the right direction. It looks more like JS conflict.

```js
 <!-- - Scripts for login modal dialog  -->
 <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 
 
 <!-- - Scripts for landing page(jquery.scrolly.min.js makes the menu dropdown once mouseover is on it and also animates scrolling with easing) -->
 <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="assets/js/jquery.scrolly.min.js"></script> 
   <script src="assets/js/jquery.dropotron.min.js"></script>
   <script src="assets/js/jquery.scrollex.min.js"></script>
   <script src="assets/js/skel.min.js"></script>
   <script src="assets/js/util.js"></script>
   <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="assets/js/ie/respond.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
   <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
   

<script type="text/javascript">
    var $s = jQuery.noConflict();
    $s(document).ready(function() {
      $s(document).on('click','.signup-tab',function(){
        .preventDefault();
        $('#signup-taba').tab('show');
      }); 
 
      $s(document).on('click','.signin-tab',function(){
       .preventDefault();
        $s('#signin-taba').tab('show');
      });
      
      $s(document).on('click','.forgetpass-tab',function(){
        .preventDefault();
        $s('#forgetpass-taba').tab('show');
    });
</script>


<script>
var $k = jQuery.noConflict();
     $k(document).ready(function(){
       
   //Check to see if the window is top if not then display button
 $(window).scroll(function(){
  if ($k(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
   $k('.scrollToTop').fadeIn();
  } else {
   $k('.scrollToTop').fadeOut();
  }
 });
 
 //Click event to scroll to top
 $k('.scrollToTop').click(function(){
  $k('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},800);
  return false;
 });
     }); 
  </script>
```

Comment: @j08691 ..can you help on this?

Answer (score 0):

I think I had a similar problem with jquery.dropotron.js : I couldn't trigger a modal from a link inside a `<li>`tag. The issue came from jquery.dropotron.js which prevented the link from doing anything if href was blank("") or has hash (#). Solved by commenting on the corresponding line:

```
`if (href.length == 0 ||    href == '#'){
    //e.preventDefault();
}
else
    e.stopPropagation();`
```

I wish it could help you... Sorry for my english.